# Get unique lines from log using grep and tail

Tags: command-line, log, text-processing

I have the following log file. I want to extract the last 10 unique entries from this file. Is it possible to do with grep and tail?

```
2016-04-18 10:13:11,925 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.7088348025036650 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 10:13:12,383 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.9277403071419588 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 10:13:14,000 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.5617050735043505 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 10:13:18,305 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.3502119403604215 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 10:13:25,571 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.1448386101904803 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 10:13:42,529 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.6017618280263232 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 10:21:20,257 (glastopf.glastopf) 150.70.188.165 requested GET / on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 10:35:27,775 (glastopf.glastopf) 150.70.173.55 requested GET / on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 10:44:21,799 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.8457383350172993 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 10:44:23,550 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.2291251627482913 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 10:44:24,885 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.9121516725350658 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 10:44:28,611 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.6517709326810913 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 10:44:36,656 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.3339893597346100 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 10:44:52,579 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.9653746532564283 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 11:07:15,576 (glastopf.glastopf) 204.12.196.236 requested GET / on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 11:14:46,990 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.6323574164650954 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 11:14:49,798 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.1343994230148844 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 11:14:50,923 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.2092851733275502 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 11:14:54,015 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.6364011485956100 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 11:15:02,021 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.2105667716533854 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 11:15:17,763 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.5330510476532333 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 11:45:51,204 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.7162577798366348 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 11:45:51,456 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.4097472747050946 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 11:45:53,562 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.0435891326571879 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 11:45:57,368 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.9764200678378154 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 11:46:05,598 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.2539390798717596 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 11:53:59,103 (glastopf.glastopf) 150.70.173.9 requested GET / on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 12:16:07,343 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.0022258971071879 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 12:16:07,411 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.6543056525672964 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 12:16:09,210 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.0771392409002968 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 12:16:21,475 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.4621648610735409 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 12:16:37,413 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.1810763849106982 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 12:46:31,160 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.0759114015016254 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 12:46:33,023 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.9823929541441208 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 12:46:42,262 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.1670975464416704 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 12:46:44,977 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.3061602425336546 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 12:47:00,555 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.5692431772822398 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 12:50:34,078 (glastopf.glastopf) 150.70.188.178 requested GET / on 711b3fb7d875:80
```

So basically I want the last 10 unique log entries, identified by unique IPs.

EDIT. Example last two unique entries:

```
2016-04-18 12:47:00,555 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.5692431772822398 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 12:50:34,078 (glastopf.glastopf) 150.70.188.178 requested GET / on 711b3fb7d875:80
```

Comment: How do you define "unique entries"? There are no duplicate lines, so are you excluding some fields?

Comment: For instance in the log file you get the last 10 entries based on unique source IP addresses

Comment: You may want to look into the `uniq` command.

Comment: If it does not work with the below answer, I will try out unique command by `|` between `grep` and `tail`

Comment: You can group all *consecutive* lines containing the same IP with `uniq -f 3 -w 15 log.txt`.

Comment: (The results will contain the *first* line of each group, however...)

Comment: Using the `uniq` command as instructed? Ok I'll keep that in mind! Thankyou

Comment: Please say if it does what you want, then I will post a more elaborate answer. You can also make it read on standard input of course (`... | uniq -f 3 -w 15`).

Comment: `unique` command is also working thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sort` with a bit of help from `tac`:

```
sort -k4,4 file.log | tac | sort -uk4,4 | sort -k1,2
```

To get last 10 entries, send to `tail -10` at the end:

```
sort -k4,4 file.log | tac | sort -uk4,4 | sort -k1,2 | tail -10
```

- `-k` option of `sort` let us `sort` by space separated field number as key
- `tac` will reverse the lines of input content i.e. last goes first and first goes last; this is needed as `sort -u` will output the first entry as unique while using key-wise `sort` i.e. not all the lines have similar content but they match on a specific field

**Example:**

```
$ sort -k4,4 file.log | tac | sort -uk4,4 | sort -k1,2
2016-04-18 10:21:20,257 (glastopf.glastopf) 150.70.188.165 requested GET / on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 10:35:27,775 (glastopf.glastopf) 150.70.173.55 requested GET / on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 11:07:15,576 (glastopf.glastopf) 204.12.196.236 requested GET / on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 11:53:59,103 (glastopf.glastopf) 150.70.173.9 requested GET / on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 12:47:00,555 (glastopf.glastopf) 115.239.248.245 requested GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.5692431772822398 on 711b3fb7d875:80
2016-04-18 12:50:34,078 (glastopf.glastopf) 150.70.188.178 requested GET / on 711b3fb7d875:80
```

Comment: Write now I have 

`sudo grep "GET" /home/tsec/prototype/logs/glastopf.log | tail -n 10 > /home/tsec/prototype/logs/extractedlogs/glastopfresult.log`

So with your example I can use sort after grep? Or like so 


`sudo grep "GET" /home/tsec/prototype/logs/glastopf.log | sort -k4,4 | tac | sort -uk4,4 | sort -k1,2 | tail -n 10 > /home/tsec/prototype/logs/extractedlogs/glastopfresult.log`

Comment: @firepro20 if `grep` produces the same output you have posted as input sample, then Yes.

Answer (score 0):

The `uniq` command can be used to eliminate all *consecutive* lines which are identical in whole or in part. By default, it only operates on whole lines. That is, if in a file you have several identical consecutive lines, `uniq` removes the duplicates.

```
$ cat foo.txt 
foo
foo
foo
bar
baz
baz
foo
foo
$ uniq foo.txt 
foo
bar
baz
foo
```

In order to remove all duplicate lines, even non-consecutive ones, it can be run after `sort`:

```
$ sort foo.txt | uniq
bar
baz
foo
```

Some flags can be used in order to only consider one part of a line when determining duplicates. Here we want to consider only IP addresses, which are in the fourth column, so first we need to tell `uniq` to disregard the first three columns, this is done with the `-f` flag. And after that we need to tell it to only consider the IP addresses. This one can be tricky because we can only tell it to considet a fixed number of characters (with the `-w` flag), but IP addresses can vary in length. Fortunately here this is not a problem because IP addresses are always followed by `requested`, so even if the first few characters of this word are included in the comparison, it will have no effect on whether a line is correctly detected as a duplicate. In the end, applying `uniq -f 3 - w 15` to the input seems to produce the desired result.

One additional thing to note is that when we only consider one part of lines in the duplicates detection, all the lines in the group of "duplicates" need not be entirely identical, and so we must decide which one will be printed in the output. `uniq` prints the first one, but can be made to print the last one by first running the input through `tac`.

Comment: is there a way to use grep to ignore lines with 141.8. .. contained in them BUT get lines that have GET? Right now I have this but I must be doing something wrong

`sudo grep -v '^141.8.83.213' && "GET" /home/tsec/prototype/logs/glastopf.log | sort -k4,4 | tac | sort -uk4,4 | sort -k1,2 | tail -n 10 > /home/tsec/prototype/logs/ext$`

Comment: @firepro20 This is a different question so please ask it separately.

Comment: sorry my bad !!